# jQuery function losing the called elements and only keeping the last caller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a parallax site, and I want to ease out the elements when the scrolling has stopped. So I developed a plugin to detect when the scrolling stops, and once it stops, then smooth out the movement of the element (The object moves 5 pixels on to the direction in which the user was scrolling). It works but only to the last element that the plugin was applied to. When i was trying to debug, I see that both elements are still in effect inside the `$(window).scroll(function(event) {` but once we reach `$(window).scrollStopped(function(){` only the last element is in effect. Any solutions?

```
// Scroll Direction set
var lastScrollTop = 0, scrollDirection = "";
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       scrollDirection = "down";
   } else {
      scrollDirection = "up";
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});

// Scroll Stopped detection
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {          
    $(this).scroll(function(){
        var self = this, $this = $(self);
        if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
          clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
        }
        $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,250,self));
    });
};

// Smooth ending
$.fn.smoothStop = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function(event) {

            $(window).scrollStopped(function(){
                var top = parseFloat($this.css("top"));

                if(scrollDirection == "down")
                {
                    console.log(top, $this);
                    var new_top = top + 5;
                     $this.animate({
                        top: new_top + 'px'},
                        1000);
                }
                else{
                    var new_top = top - 5;
                     $this.animate({
                        top: new_top + 'px'},
                        1000);
                }
            });
        });


    };
```

`$(".g6").smoothStop();
$(".g2").smoothStop();`

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P4bmv/1/)**

Comment: Can you prepare a jsFiddle?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minute

Comment: There http://jsfiddle.net/P4bmv/1/  I changed the movement to 15px so the movement is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Scroll Stopped detection
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {        
    $(this).scroll(function(){                      <-- this is the window
        var self = this, $this = $(self);
        if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
          clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));    <----timeout is removed from window
        }
        $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,250,self)); <----timeout is set to window
    });
};
```

basically you are trying to run multiple events, but you end up storing those multiple events in the same memory location. So when you add a new one, it cancells out the previous entry.